# WPF right align ribbon button

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control, ribboncontrolslibrary

Is there a way to align a ribbon button to the right? I'm using Microsoft ribbon.

Thanks,

Raymond

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please explain in more detail what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already solved in this link.
put it in ribbon group.

[RibbonButton not aligning properly in Ribbon Control in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707779/ribbonbutton-not-aligning-properly-in-ribbon-control-in-wpf)